# How to Push only the updated cells using RDA

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-ce, rda

In my inventory mobile application , i use RDA.
using the mobile device ,i update only the Barcode of a particular Item which is in the Item Master(.sdf file). then I push the tables to the SQL Server.
there is a web application handles all the other functionality , including Item Master Changes.
for and eg.

(1) I pull the Item master to the Mobile Device.
(2)change the Item Name from the Web application.(NOT FROM DEVICE)
(3)Update Bar code from the Device
(4)push table from mobile Device to SQL Server.

In this situation Old Item Name is replaced.
My need is only to update the Barcode.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use SubmitSQL instead?